# Перенос таблица из MS SQL Server Express в MySQL без дублей

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Доброго времени суток.

Необходимо из таблицы MS SQL Server Express перенести данные в стороннюю таблицу на MySQL.

Пытаюсь выполнить следующий запрос, но он создает дублированные записи. Как их можно избежать?

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(YAM, 'SELECT * FROM ia.recognized_numbers') (numcar, time, type)
SELECT param0, date, objid
FROM i.dbo.PROTOCOL
WHERE action = 'NUMBER_DETECTED'
    AND date not IN (SELECT time FROM OPENQUERY(YAM, 'SELECT * FROM ia.recognized_numbers'))
```

Comment: Т.е., насколько я понял, в целевой таблице у вас какие-то записи уже есть. _"создает дублированные записи"_ дублированные с чем, с теми, что уже были в целевой таблице до вставки, или сами вставляемые записи содержат дубликаты?

Comment: При вставке создает дубли. Как будто условие <code>AND date not IN </code> вообще не выполняется.

Comment: В целевой таблице какой набор столбцов должен быть уникален ?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была решена введением дополнительного уникального столбца. 
Записи дублировались из-за того что в MSSQL Server timestamp хранил в виде `2016-05-30 01:44:36.043`, а в MySQL запись попадала в виде `2016-05-30 01:44:36.000`. Из-за чего столбец времени нельзя было использовать как уникальный из-за разницы записи.

P.s.: Спасибо за подсказку [@i-one](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/193999/i-one)